# JPA/Hibernate Native Queries do not recognize Parameters with EmbeddedId

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate/JPA to execute native MySql queries. I want to get the value of the counter.

For example the following query crash:

```
"SELECT sizeList FROM myCounter WHERE myColA=?1 AND myColB=?2 AND LIMIT 1"
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [1] did not exist
```

Sources:

Method:

```
@Override
public Long getSizeList(String myColA, String myColB) {
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("MyCounter.getSizeList");
    q.setParameter(1, myColA);
    q.setParameter(2, myColB);
    return (Long) q.getSingleResult();
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myCounter")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyCounter.getSizeList", query = "SELECT sizeList FROM myCounter WHERE myColA=?1 AND myColB=?2 AND LIMIT 1", resultClass = MyCounter.class)})
public class MyCounter implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected MyCounterPK myCounterPK;
@Column(name = "sizeList")
private BigInteger sizeList;

public PostListCounterPTTESLTTT() {
}

...

public BigInteger getSizeList() {
    return sizeList;
}

}
```

Embeddable:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyCounterPK implements Serializable {
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "myColA")
private String myColA;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "myColB")
private String myColB;

public MyCounterPK() {
}

...

}
```

Does anyone know how to use setParameter() in this case ?

I tried with:

```
//case 1:
"SELECT sizeList FROM myCounter WHERE myColA=?1 AND myColB=?2 AND LIMIT 1"
q.setParameter(1, myColA); //the same error

//case 2:
"SELECT sizeList FROM myCounter WHERE myColA=?1 AND myColB=?2 AND LIMIT 1"
q.setParameter("1", myColA); //the same error

//case 3:
"SELECT sizeList FROM myCounter WHERE myColA=:myColA AND myColB=:myColB AND LIMIT 1"
q.setParameter("myColA", myColA); //the same error
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("MyCounter.getSizeList");
```

Try this:

```
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("MyCounter.getSizeList");
```